# Why are Lie Algebras/ Lie Groups so much like crossed modules, and not?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-groups, higher-category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

A crossed module consists of a pair of groups $G$ and $H$ with a group homomorphism, $t:H \rightarrow G$, and $\alpha: G \times H \rightarrow H$ that defines an action of $G$ on $H$, $\tilde{\alpha}$: via 
$\alpha(g,h)=\tilde{\alpha}(g) (h)$. These maps satisfy,
$t(\alpha(g,h))= g t(h) g^{-1}$, and $\alpha(t(h), h')= h h' h^{-1}$.

According to Baez and Lauda [HDA 5](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307200) example 48, page 64, a Lie group and a Lie algebra can be used to construct a crossed module. The construction is to let $\alpha$ be defined via the adjoint map, and to let $t$ be defined as the trivial map $t(v)=1$ for all $v \in g$.

To simplify my question, suppose that $g = su(2)$, and $G=SU(2)$. Now consider $\alpha(g,v) = g v g^{-1}$ for $g\in G$ and $v\in g$. Define $t(v) = \exp{v}$. We can compute that $t(\alpha(g,h))= g t(h) g^{-1}$. However,

1. The [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) precludes that $t$ is a homomorphism, and
2. $\tilde{\alpha}(\exp{h}) (h')$ is rotation of $h'$ about the vector $h$ through an angle $ 2 |h|$. 
   In other words, $\tilde{\alpha}(\exp{h}) (h') = (\exp{h}) h' (\exp{(-h)}).$

So the lack of homomorphism and the wrong Peiffer identity puts a damper on things. Is there a ``crossed module" like name for such a structure? For example, is it related to a $2$-group in any sense?

This question may be related to [Theo's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9220/what-does-the-generating-function-x-1-e-x-count) about Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: I tried to fix the html: on my computer, at least, everything was displaying as the same link.  (Note: the "preview" feature for writing question uses a different implementation of MarkDown than the actual website does for posting.  In particular, preview runs in the browser, whereas when a question is posted the server does the work.)  I still don't know why the link to Wikipedia fails.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't have an answer to your questions, but I wanted to make a remark about the HDA5 example.  Namely, a good way to think about the Lie algebra is as the infinitesimal neighborhood of the identity in the group.  A better way is to take the group over the dual numbers `$K[e]/e^2$`, and the Lie algebra is precisely the points near the identity.  Then the map "$t$" in the HDA5 example simply takes a point in this larger group to its "shadow", and so clearly respects all structure.  Whereas in your construction, you are trying to take an "infinitesimal" quantity and scale it up.

Comment: @Theo 1 and 2. Thanks for both. I am having a bad time with
html and TeX on this site. A recent post was edited a few times by others. Arrgh!