# Todd class and Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff, or the curious number $12$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

The number $12$ (or, probably we shall say Bernoulli numbers in general) appears in many places in Mathematics, sometimes leading to unexpected connections between different topics.

For instance, some time ago there was a very interesting explanation for

1) its occurrence in the Todd class

and

2) its occurrence in the Euler-Maclaurin formula

in terms of Riemann-Roch for toric varieties, as explained in:

[Euler-Maclaurin formula and Riemann-Roch](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10667/euler-maclaurin-formula-and-riemann-roch)

===========================================================

My question is, will there be some relation between 1) and

3) its occurrence in the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

I guess this might be related to some explicit local expressions in some method of proving the index theorem on Lie groups, or even the Duflo map (which I don't really understand).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't this a numerology question?! At least you don't ask why 12 is close to an integer... :-)

Comment: Hi Wadim, I edited the question make it somehow more "feasible" :-)

Comment: I'll be more convinced after seeing an answer. 12 already appeared in one of today questions about $a^2+b^2=c^2$...

Comment: A baker's dozen is 13. I don't know about Campbell and Hausdorff.

Comment: 
Possibly related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9220/what-does-the-generating-function-x-1-e-x-count

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff_formula? Please, clarify in what way the explanation there involving the expansion of $\operatorname{ad}(X)/(e^{\operatorname{ad}(X)}-1)$ found there is lacking?

Answer (score 15):

The answer to your question is the following: given two non-commutative variables $x$ and $y$ one has 
$$
log(e^xe^y)=x+e^{ad_x}\frac{ad_x}{e^{ad_x}-1}(y)+O(y^2)
$$

It is not the appearance of $12$ that is intriguing, but the appearance of the Todd series in algebraic geometry. It suggests that there is a group hidden somewhere... and this is indeed the case. This group is the derived loop space of your favorite algebraic variety $X$, and its tangent Lie algebra is the shifted tangent sheaf $T_X[-1]$, with Lie bracket given by the Atiyah class (the fact that the Atiyah class gives rize to a Lie structure was [discovered by Kapranov](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9704009)).

The universal enveloping algebra of this Lie algebra is the Hochschild complex of $X$. One then gets a nice dictionnary between the Lie side and the algebraic geometry side. E.g.:

- any object in the derived category of $X$ turns out to be a representation of this Lie algebra.
- Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt is Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg.
- the Duflo isomorphism is the Kontsevich-Caldararu isomorphism between the Harmonic and Hochschild structures.
- there is also an relation between closed embeddings in algebraic geometry and inclusions of Lie algebras.
- ...

Comment: In item 1 "derived category of X " do you mean current sheaves on X?  PS very useful answer! 

Comment: Coherent sheaves


Comment: I actualy mean quasi-coherent sheaves (the action of $T_X[-1]$ on a given one $E$ is given by the Atiyah class of $E$). 