# "What does f(n) count?" - in search for a paper

Tags: co.combinatorics, reference-request

I am desperately searching for a paper I once have read, but cannot find anymore. It was about a counting function f(n) - the only thing I remember is that f's expression contained n! and 2<sup>n</sup> - and the question in the title was something like "What does f(n) count?". The paper compared three or so different approaches, and was written as a trialog.

> Can someone point me to this paper?

If you know about other papers on this question - "What does f(n) count?", with f(n) any counting-but-what function, I'd be happy to learn about them.

Comment: A negative result: I tried sticking "what does" into the title field at Math Reviews and got many hits but didn't get anything like what you're looking for. 

Comment: I also searched for "what does" in math titles at the arXiv and found nothing relevant. 

Comment: Thanks for the endeavor, but that's why I said *something like "What does f(n) count?"*. It also could have been "What's f(n) the number of?" or something like that.

Comment: I am afraid you would have to know the paper, because you won't find it by searching.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just hoping to save someone else the trouble of going down the one particular blind alley. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be [*The answer is $2^n·n$! What's the question?*](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2589493) by Gary Gordon (Amer. Math. Monthly  **106** (1999),  no. 7, 636–645)?

Comment: @Hans ...and thank you! I just enjoyed a little Monday morning procrastination skimming this nice paper.

Comment: In case you don't have JSTOR, here is a free version on author's website: http://webbox.lafayette.edu/~gordong/pubs/2%5En.pdf

Answer (score 2):

One question of this kind can be found on MO:

[What does the generating function $x/(1 - e^{-x})$ count?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9220/what-does-the-generating-function-x-1-e-x-count)