# Examples of integer sequences coincidences

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, big-list, integer-sequences, oeis

For the time being, the [OEIS](http://oeis.org) website contains  almost $300000$ sequences. Each of these sequences is the mark of a specific mathematical concept. Sometimes two (or more) distinct concepts have the same mark, which suggests a connection between *a priori* independent mathematical areas. The most famous example like that is perhaps the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) sequence: [A000108](http://oeis.org/A000108).

**Question**: What are the examples of pair of integer sequences coinciding on all the *known* terms, but for which the coincidence for all the terms is unknown?

Cheating is not allowed. By cheating I mean *artificial* examples like:
 $u_n = v_n =n$ for $n \neq 10$, and if RH is true then $u_{10} = v_{10} = 10$, else $u_{10}+1 = v_{10} = 1$.
The existence of an OEIS entry could act as safety.

*EDIT*: I would like to point out that all the answers below are about pair of integer sequences which were already conjectured to be the same, and of course they are on-topic (and some of them are very nice). Note that such examples can be found by searching something like "conjectured to be identical" on OEIS, as I did for some of my own examples below...
Now, a more surprising kind of answer would be a (non-cheating) pair of integer sequences which are the same on the *known* entries, but for which there is no evidence *a priori* that they are the same for all the entries or that they are related (i.e. the precise meaning of a *coincidence*). Such examples, also on-topic, could reveal some unexpected connections in mathematics, but could be harder to find...

Comment: Related: [Longest coinciding pair of integer sequences known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52101/longest-coinciding-pair-of-integer-sequences-known).

Comment: @dxiv: I was about to write the same comment. It should be precise that the post you linked requests pair of integer sequences coinciding up to a large $N$ but differing after that, whereas here we request that there is no known difference.

Comment: Right, of course. The two questions are related, but distinctly different.

Comment: I think http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/mathar.pdf belongs here as a comment, to remind us that some conjectures reformulating definitions as recurrences can be automatically proved.

Answer (score 46):

A historical example, in the sense that the conjectural equality has been refuted: [A180632](https://oeis.org/A180632) (Minimum length of a string of letters that contains every permutation of $n$ letters as sub-strings) was conjectured equal to [A007489](https://oeis.org/A007489) ($\sum_{k=1}^n k!$).

The exact value of A180632 at $n=6$ is still unknown, but it must be less than the conjectured value of $1!+2!+\cdots+6!=873$, because the following string of length 872 contains every permutation of 123456 as a substring:

> 12345612345162345126345123645132645136245136425136452136451234651234156234152634152364152346152341652341256341253641253461253416253412653412356412354612354162354126354123654132654312645316243516243156243165243162543162453164253146253142653142563142536142531645231465231456231452631452361452316453216453126435126431526431256432156423154623154263154236154231654231564213564215362415362145362154362153462135462134562134652134625134621536421563421653421635421634521634251634215643251643256143256413256431265432165432615342613542613452613425613426513426153246513246531246351246315246312546321546325146325416325461325463124563214563241563245163245613245631246532146532416532461532641532614532615432651436251436521435621435261435216435214635214365124361524361254361245361243561243651423561423516423514623514263514236514326541362541365241356241352641352461352416352413654213654123

Comment: I did not notice that this discovery is yours: https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5108. Did you find something for $n=7$?

Comment: Today's Numberphile video is on the superpermutations: https://youtu.be/wJGE4aEWc28

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux No; but I’m trying to capitalise on the interest the video has generated to gather a group of people who are interested in pushing the computations further, so we may see some progress as a result of that.

Answer (score 29):

[EDITED]
The classic example is [A000396](https://oeis.org/A000396):  "Perfect numbers n: n is equal to the sum of the proper divisors of n" 
and  A000668(n)*(A000668(n)+1)/2 where [A000668](https://oeis.org/A000668) are the Mersenne primes.

They are the same if and only if there are no odd perfect numbers.

See also [sequences which agree for a long time](https://oeis.org/wiki/Index_to_OEIS:_Section_Se#sequences_which_agree_for_a_long_time).

Comment: There was a time, in the 1970s, when the number of known perfect numbers was equal to the number of known sporadic simple groups (but I don't think anyone conjectured that they'd be equal when all was said and done).

Comment: Following those links, it looks like the sequences diverge after 2658455991569831744654692615953842176. Is that an error in one of the OEIS pages?

Comment: There is a careless mistake in your answer because [A136007](https://oeis.org/A136007) is a strict subsequence of the Mersenne primes [A000668](https://oeis.org/A000668), and so [A152953](https://oeis.org/A152953) is also a strict subsequence of what you expected. You should write a(n) = A000668(n)*(A000668(n)+1)/2 or [A006516](https://oeis.org/A006516)([A000043](https://oeis.org/A000043)(n)) or [A139256](https://oeis.org/A139256)(n)/2.

Comment: Oops, OK.  Editing...

Answer (score 14):

Just another instance of the (second) [Strong Law of Small Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers):

We have [A157656](https://oeis.org/A157656)(n) = [A059100](https://oeis.org/A059100)(n-1) for all known terms (i.e., $n\leq 6$), but it's also known that A157656(29) > A059100(28). So, the two sequences diverge somewhere.

Answer (score 10):

Some sequences have conjectured formulas, for example the following which I encountered recently, [A227404](https://oeis.org/A227404).

$a_n$ is the total number of inversions, among all permutations on $[n]$ that is a single cycle in the cycle decomposition.
It is conjectured that $a_n = n! (3n-1)/12$, and I find it rather amazing that there is no proof of this.

Comment: I understand that your point is more general, but the formula for $a_n$ you mention can -- if I'm not mistaken -- be proven by counting the number of cyclic permutations $\sigma$ for which $\{a,b\}$ is an inversion. Indeed, if $a<b$ we must have $\sigma(a)>\sigma(b)$ which (as $\sigma(a)=a$, $\sigma(b)=b$, and $\{a,b\}=\{\sigma(a),\sigma(b)\}$ are disallowed) gives $\binom{n}{2} - n + b -a$ options for $(\sigma(a),\sigma(b))$. Each of these options can be extended to $(n-3)!$ cyclic permutations. So $a_n = (n-3)! \sum_{a < b} (\binom{n}{2} - n + b - a) = n!(3n-1)/12$.

Comment: Similar to http://oeis.org/A216239

Comment: "No proof" often means that the sequence did not attract enough attention.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: Yes, indeed. I like the proof given in the comment - I have another family of combinatorial objects that seem to be in bijection with these, so hence, I was interested in the proof :)

Comment: I've edited the sequence and removed "conjectured" from the formula.

Answer (score 4):

1. The least prime $p$ such that $p+2n$ is also prime: [A020483](https://oeis.org/A020483)$(n)$, and the smallest number $x$ such that $\sigma(x+2n) = \sigma(x)+2n$: [A054906](https://oeis.org/A054906)$(n)$.
2. The smallest prime in which a digit appears $n$ times: [A084673](https://oeis.org/A084673)$(n)$, and the smallest prime containing exactly $n$ $1$'s: [A037055](https://oeis.org/A037055)$(n)$, for $n>1$.
3. The number of subwords of length $n$ in the infinite word generated by $a \to aab, \  b \to  b$ : [A006697](https://oeis.org/A006697)$(n)$, and the maximal number of distinct nonempty substrings of any binary string of length $n$, plus one: [A094913](https://oeis.org/A094913)$(n)+1$.
4. The number of distinct values taken by ${\omega}$^${\omega}$^${\dots}$^${\omega}$ (with $n$ $\omega$'s and parentheses inserted in all possible ways) where $\omega$ is the first transfinite ordinal omega: [A199812](https://oeis.org/A199812)$(n)$, and the number of unlabeled rooted trees with at most $n$ nodes [A087803](https://oeis.org/A087803)$(n)$, minus $n$ plus one: [A255170](https://oeis.org/A255170)$(n)$.
5. The number of transitive permutation groups of degree $n$: [A002106](https://oeis.org/A002106)$(n)$ is conjectured to be the number of Galois groups for irreducible polynomials (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of order $n$ (such groups are transitive).  It is a particular case of the [Inverse Galois problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem).

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=%22Conjectured+extension%22&sort=&language=&go=Search yields another one, not as nice though: https://oeis.org/A023054

Comment: and another one, due to Callan: https://oeis.org/A001764 - $\binom{3n}{n}/(2n+1)$ equals the number of permutations of $[n+1]$ that avoid the patterns $4-2-3-1$ and $4-2-5-1-3$ and end with an ascent.

Answer (score 3):

Another example I know is A191363, i.e., numbers $n$ such that $\sigma(n) = 2n - 2$. According to OEIS all known terms are $(a_k-1)a_k/2$ where $a_k$ is the sequence of Fermat primes (A019434).

Answer (score 0):

For example Recurrence relations of this type:$b_{n+1}+b_{n-1}=(n\alpha + \beta)b_n, n\geq 1 ,  b(0) = 0, b(1) = 1.$. with $\alpha, \beta$  real or complex appear in several contexts see  sequences :[A053983](https://oeis.org/A053983/internal), [A053984](https://oeis.org/A053984), [A058797](https://oeis.org/A058798/internal), [A058798](https://oeis.org/A058798/internal)

Comment: Your two last hyperlinks go to the same page (and no need internal format). Thanks for sharing this answer but it is a bit off_topic... We basically request a pair of integer sequences (possibly on OEIS) whose *known* terms are the same but for which it is an open problem whether the rest of the terms are also the same.